# Is it possible to update a package w/out rebuilding it from /usr/ports on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd

I'm running FreeBSD:

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD f9.XXX.org 9.0-RELEASE-p3 FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE-p3 #0: Tue Jun 12 02:52:29 UTC 2012     root@amd64-builder.daemonology.net:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
#
```

I'm getting following:

```
# portaudit | head -3
Affected package: sudo-1.8.3_1
Type of problem: sudo -- Authentication bypass when clock is reset.
Reference: http://portaudit.FreeBSD.org/764344fb-8214-11e2-9273-902b343deec9.html
#
```

Is there an easy way to update this package w/out (re)building it (no /usr/ports). I installed it through `pkg_add` (which was very easy).

*** UPDATE ***

```
# pkg_delete sudo-1.8.3_1 && pkg_add -r sudo
Fetching ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-9.0-release/Latest/sudo.tbz... Done.
#

# portaudit | head -7
Affected package: sudo-1.8.3_1
Type of problem: sudo -- Authentication bypass when clock is reset.
Reference: http://portaudit.FreeBSD.org/764344fb-8214-11e2-9273-902b343deec9.html

Affected package: sudo-1.8.3_1
Type of problem: sudo -- Potential bypass of tty_tickets constraints.
Reference: http://portaudit.FreeBSD.org/82cfd919-8213-11e2-9273-902b343deec9.html
#
```

Answer (score 1):

`pkg_delete sudo-1.8.3_1 && pkg_add -r sudo`

pkg_delete should not delete configuration files that have been changed from their defaults. If the format of the configuration file has changed you may need to update it manually.

For any automated version of this process, install `portupgrade` or one of the other similar utilities. Running `portupgrade -P sudo-1.8.3_1` would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I updated my question w/ running pkg_(delete/add) which returns me to same place where I was before.

Comment: portupgrade != package, it goes through /usr/ports.

Comment: `sudo-1.8.3_1.tbz` is the latest package available for 9.0-RELEASE AMD64. Portupgrade can use either ports or packages depending on what configuration you feed it; perhaps you should read its manpage.